# How to access TCP Socket via web client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, tcp

I have a program in an embedded device that outputs an xml string to a socket. The embedded device has lighthttpd has a web server. I want to use a web based client (no flash/silverlight) to connect to the socket and pull the xml data every second.

I looked at Node.js with Socket.io to get what I want to do, but I am not clear about how to proceed. Searching through the Node.js and Socket.io documentation and examples I see standard client-server behavior, nothing regarding what I am trying to do.

Basically, the web server is just there to accept a connection from a client on the socket that the embedded application is outputting data to. Basically the web server's purpose is to just let the client retrieve data from the raw tcp socket that the embedded application is writing to. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify), which acts as bridge between a TCP Socket and a browser.

The html client will connect to a websocket, and Websockify will listen on the websocket port and transmit data between the websocket and the tcp socket.

Comment: Hi jabe do you have any working example? i also want the same mechanism but i dont know how to use websockify in node js

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers have the ability to do HTTP requests (which can be web page requests or Ajax requests for data) and webSocket connections.  You will need to pick one of these two mechanisms if you're sticking with stock browser access.

If the lighthttpd web server in the embedded device does not support webSockets, then your choice will like be an Ajax call from the browser to your server.  This is basically just an HTTP request that make return something different than a web page (often JSON data) and is designed to fetch data from the server into a web client.

If the lighthttpd web server does support webSockets, then you could use a webSocket connection to fetch the data too.  This has an advantage of being a persistent connection and allows for the server to directly send data to the client (without the client even requesting more data) whenever it wants to (more efficient for constant updates).

An Ajax connection is generally not persistent.  A client sends an Ajax request, the server returns the answer and the connection is closed.  The next request starts a new Ajax request.

Either Ajax requests or webSocket connections should work just fine for your use.  All browsers still in use support Ajax.  WebSockets are supported in modern browsers (IE10 and higher).

---

Once you decide upon a client connection strategy, then you'd build your web app on the embedded device that served as the middleman between the browser and the data on the embedded device.  It would collect the appropriate data from the embedded device and then be able to send that to browser clients that connected and requested the data.

---

I'm not sure exactly why you mentioned node.js.  In this circumstance, it would be used as the web server and the environment for building your app and the logic that collects the data from your device and feeds it to the requesting web browser, but it sounds like you already have lighthttpd  for this purpose.  Personally, I recommend node.js if it works in your environment.  Combined with socket.io (for webSocket support), it's a very nice way to connect browsers directly to an embedded device.  I have an attic fan controller written in node.js and running on a Raspberry Pi.  The node.js app monitors temperature probes and controls relays that switch attic fans and node.js also serves as a web server for me to administer and monitor the node.js.  All-in-all, it's a pretty slick environment if you already know and like programming in Javascript and there's a rich set of add-in modules to extend its capabilities available through NPM.  If, however, your embedded device isn't a common device that there is already support for node.js on or it doesn't already have node.js on it, then you'd be facing a porting tasks to make node.js run on it which might be more work than using some other development environment that already runs on the device like lighthttpd.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making my question clearer. I just mentioned node.js as a possible example. What I needed to do was to connect to a raw tcp socket from a web browser. I solved the problem by using a bridge in between the web server and the html client.